# Alexa Echo Device doesn't show SVG image while it's showing fine in the Alexa developer console test simulator and Multimodal Responses Authoring tool

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

When updating my skill using APL, I updated one URL source of an image.
The images are hosting on a https server which has been working fine.
All I changed was to point to a SVG image file instead of a PNG file on the same location of https server.

Now the problem is, the old PNG image displays fine on my physical Echo Show 8 device at run time, and the Alexa developer console test simulator and in the Multimodal Responses Authoring tool designer.
However, the new SVG image does NOT show on my physical Echo Show 8 device, while it's still showing fine in the Alexa developer console test simulator and in the Multimodal Responses Authoring tool designer.
If I copy the SVG file URL to a browser address bar, it also can be shown fine in the browser, so there's no access issues.

Could someone tell me what's wrong here? Alexa Echo Show Device doesn't support SVG format images? But there's no document mentioning that information.

The odd thing is, I tried the SVG image in the Alexa developer console test simulator and in the Multimodal Responses Authoring tool designer, they both showing fine.

I'm expecting the SVG to be shown fine on the actual Echo Show 8 device as it did for PNG.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Alexa Vector Graphics format (AVG) to display vector graphics in APL documents. It's (sort of) a subset of SVG.

[Alexa Vector Graphics format](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/alexa-presentation-language/apl-avg-format.html)

There's a (Beta) tool in the developer console for importing & converting  SVGs.

[Import a Scalable Vector Graphic](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/alexa-presentation-language/import-svg.html)

Comment: My SVG images are dynamic, I can't pre import and convert them using the beta tool.
All i'm doing is changing the image component source URL at run time.
Also, this doesn't explain why SVG displays fine in the Alexa developer console test simulator and in the Multimodal Responses Authoring tool designer. But not in the actual Echo device. Can someone explain on this?

Comment: You're right, that's inconsistent, however the _devices_ are behaving true to the spec (by only supporting AVG).  The browser-based tools tolerating SVG doesn't change the requirements. 

Btw, I tested this before I answered, and my own test SVGs didn't display in the browser tools.

Comment: "however the devices are behaving true to the spec (by only supporting AVG)" --> Could you point me to that spec? Where did it state that the Echo devices only support AVG but not SVG? Honestly there should be a clear official document indicating what image formats are supported and what are not by the devices for skill developers, but I couldn't find it anywhere.
Also like I said, I have tons of dynamic SVG images, I can't convert them AVG one by one using the beta tool. It's not a solution for me.

Comment: I was referring to the opening sentence in the AVG page linked above: “Use the Alexa Vector Graphics (AVG) format to define vector graphics for use in APL documents.”  It doesn’t _explicitly_ say you can’t use something other than AVG but to me that’s a strong hint that AVG is _the_ supported method.  I guess it’s open to interpretation. Anyway, I don’t know of anything else in the docs about vector graphics. Maybe someone else will. Hope you find a solution.

Comment: My take on it would be that SVG isn't supported.  SVG is a very rich format and it would appear that Amazon have decided to support a subset of the SVG format via the Amazon specific AVG format.  Why else would Amazon come up with AVG + the tooling to convert SVG to AVG ? I've looked in apl.ninja and there are no examples of a SVG image being used.